# use of undeclared identifier 'segue'

Tags: xcode, segue, undeclared-identifier

I'm ready to bang my head on the table.   Or maybe I'm just too tired.   Can anyone lend a second set of eyes and tell me why the last if statement below yields an error?

Thanks Much

```
#import "BAWelcomeViewController.h"

@interface BAWelcomeViewController ()

@end

@implementation BAWelcomeViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (![PFUser currentUser]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Show Login View" sender:self];
        return;
    }
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Show Main View" sender:self];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isequaltostring:@"Show Login View") {
        //do something here
    }

}
```

Comment: Normally error messages provide a clue as to what is wrong. How can we help you without it?

Comment: It looks to me like you've put a `prepareForSegue...` implementation inside a `performSegue...` method.

Answer (score 1):

The context is a bit sparse, so hard to say for sure what you mean to do, but it looks like you've copy and pasted the code from elsewhere;

```
- (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isequaltostring:@"Show Login View") {
```

The method is already called with identifier, not segue, so what you need is probably just;

```
- (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {

    if ([identifier isequaltostring:@"Show Login View"]) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isequaltostring:@"Show Login View") {
        //do something here
    }

}
```

is incorrect. Try

```
- (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"Show Login View"]) {
        //do something here
    }

}
```

You don't have a `segue` to call `identifier` on. Also fixed some code mistakes.

Comment: Ok definitely tired… How could I have missed that? :-)  Thanks Terry!